In VSCode, is there a shortcut to move the cursor to the beginning of the line from arbitray position of the line, but after indentation?
For example, I want to move the cursor to before x but after the space before x(like the default behavior of JetBrains IDEs). When I use Ctrl+a in macOS, it move to the left of first space.
fn main() {
    // TODO: Add the missing keyword.
    x = 5;

    println!("x has the value {x}");
}



Windows/Linux: Ctrl + [left arrow]
On Mac: Cmd + [left arrow]


As I guess, VS Code does not support that functionality directly. But we can config that feature in keybindings.json.
Then, you may opend the keybindings.json file locates on /Code/User/keybindings.json on macOS, and add custom script
{
    "key": "cmd+l",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "wrappedLineFirstNonWhitespaceCharacter"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}

to the end of the file.
According to this you can press CMD + L to move the cursor to the first non-whitespace character of a line. And, also you can customize the script with cursorMove command using args. You can browse args here VS Code keybindings docs.
